# permission denied to access property 'tostring' error in Firefox, and some jQuery plugin is not working

Tags: jquery, firefox

I use 2 jQuery plugins on one webpage, but now working in Firefox 21, with error message :

> "permission denied to access property 'tostring'".

use

- jQuery 1.9.1,
- jQuery Tools(jquerytools.org) plugin,
- flexslider(http://www.woothemes.com/flexslider/) plugin.

I found "permission denied to access property 'tostring'" error message in developer tool's 'Web Console' window, in Firefox.

and some jQuery plugin is not working. I use 'tab(mouseover option)' of jQuery Tools, but this function is not working. but, flexslider plugin is work.

I found solution for this error, but I can't found satisfactory solution(some people say that just a browser's bug. really?).

please help me and thanks your attention.

Answer (score 1):

I'm sorry to see no replies to this because I am seeing the same behavior.

Specifically, it says:

> An error occurred while attempting to process /views/ajax: Permission denied to access property 'toString'

This apparently only happens in Firefox v.18.0.x or later so am I correct to assume Mozilla introduced this bug? I know they are working on their own mobile OS platform -- wondering if that has anything to do with it.